# CSS: show style on hover over multiple divs placed one over another

Tags: css, hover

I have 2 divs of different dimension placed one over the other. So there is a common intersection area. There is CSS :hover rule set for both the divs.
If I hover over each div then the rule applies. But if I move over the intersection area, only the top div hover is actuated.

When the mouse hovers on the area of intersection, I want the :hover rule to actuate for both the divs.

Please see example code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/souvikbasu/881u0r7y/)

On hover over the divs, the border shows up in black. I want both the div borders to show up when mouse hovers over the intersection area.

The same code is copy pasted below for reference:

HTML

```
<div class='lower-layer'></div>
<div class='upper-layer'></div>
```

CSS

```
.upper-layer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.lower-layer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position:absolute; 
}

.upper-layer:hover {
  border: solid 2px black;   
}

.lower-layer:hover {
  border: solid 2px black;   
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: To make the question more explicit. I want the border of both the divs to show up only when the mouse is within the green box in the image below

[image]

If the mouse is over the black boxes like in image below then only the individual div under the mouse should show its border.

[image]

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/881u0r7y/1/)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tushar. In your change, both the borders show up if I hover over anywhere. I want both the borders to show up only when the mouse is over the intersection area where the 2 divs overlap each other. If the mouse is over a single div only that div border should show up.

Comment: Can you use jQuery, because I don't think this will be possible by using only CSS

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/881u0r7y/3/)

Comment: will prefer to do it using CSS only as the actual app is in angular and integrating jQuery in it might create some problem

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/881u0r7y/4/) may help you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add `:hover` to your containing `div` (**span**) instead of each of the inner `divs`;

```
.upper-layer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
.lower-layer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
}
span:hover div {
    border: solid 2px black;
}
```

Here's the Jsfiddle: 
[Double Hover](https://jsfiddle.net/881u0r7y/2/)

Comment: In your answer, both the borders show up if I hover over anywhere. I want both the borders to show up only when the mouse is over the intersection area where the 2 divs overlap each other. If the mouse is over a single div only that div border should show up.

Comment: Not with css, as with css only one element is hovered (from overlapping non-nested elements). jQuery can help but it is not trivial..check out the link: https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7V8AN/