# Apply style when hover over overlapping elements

Tags: css, html, sass

I'm trying to apply some animations when i hover over the overlapping parts of two elements. How can i do this?

I want to apply styles when i hover over an element with the class `main` and ONE of the directional classes(`left, right, top, bottom`). Basically only when i hover over the inner triangles(inside the big square) and never the outer ones.

Using this example, i want to apply styling/animations when i hover over the areas `LM, TM, RM or BM` and not when i hover over `L, T, R or B`.

```
           ^
          / \
         /   \
        /  T  \
       /       \
      /_________\
     /|\       /|\
    / | \ TM  / | \
   /  |  \   /  |  \
  /   |   \ /   |   \
 <  L | LM x RM | R  >
  \   |   / \   |   /
   \  |  /   \  |  /
    \ | / BM  \ | /
     \|/___ ___\|/
      \         /
       \       /
        \  B  /
         \   /
          \ /
           v
```

Tried something like:

```
&:hover&.main:hoover ~ .slider {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

but this didn't work. Can't really figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

```css
.hoover-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}

.slider {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
}

.main {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute; 
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  left: -17.5px;
}

.left:hover ~ .slider {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }

.top {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  top: -17.5px;
  
}
  .top:hover ~ .slider {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }

.right {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: gold;
  left: 32px;
  
}

  .right:hover ~ .slider {
    background-color: gold;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

.bottom {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: crimson;
  top: 32px;
  

}
  .bottom:hover ~ .slider {
    background-color: crimson;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="hoover-box">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25sdwexf/98/)**

Comment: what is not working ? i see some effect

Comment: I want the effect only when i hover over the inner triangles(the parts of the rotated squares that overlap with the big square). Not when i hover over the outer triangles like how it works now.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I cant use scss in the snippet?

Answer (score 1):

As you've constructed the elements, it's not possible. There's a simpler example: [CSS: show style on hover over multiple divs placed one over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345583/css-show-style-on-hover-over-multiple-divs-placed-one-over-another). Hover events are propagated to the element highest in the [z-index stack](https://tiffanybbrown.com/2015/09/css-stacking-contexts-wtf/index.html) (but properties other than z-index affect this).

To make this work as you would like, you'd need to create triangles for the TM, RM, LM, and BM sections and set hover events there.

Below is a simplified version I made using transparent boxes as overlays instead of triangles:

```css
.hoover-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}

.slider {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: background 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
}

.main {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute; 
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  left: -17.5px;
}

.lm:hover ~ .slider {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }

.top {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  top: -17.5px;
  
}
  .tm:hover ~ .slider {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }

.right {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: gold;
  left: 32px;
  
}

  .rm:hover ~ .slider {
    background-color: gold;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

.bottom {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: crimson;
  top: 32px;
  

}
  .bm:hover ~ .slider {
    background-color: crimson;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

.bm, .lm, .rm, .tm {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.tm {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}

.bm {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.rm {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.lm {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoover-box">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="rm"></div>
  <div class="lm"></div>
  <div class="bm"></div>
  <div class="tm"></div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is pretty much the same as what @weBer suggested. It also comes with the same issues where lm, tm etc. elements have overlapping areas that only allow one hover-event to trigger. For example if you hover over the bottom part of the LM area, the BM hover-event will trigger.

Comment: @mTv In that case, what you need is a direction-aware hover effect like on CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/direction-aware-hover-effects/. Just keep in mind, there is no CSS-only solution.

Comment: Yea I think i might have to change my approach. Found this aswell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107646/how-can-i-maintain-proper-boundaries-on-css-triangles-when-hovering-with-cursor. Looks pretty good.